# Why would simpledialog dialog not pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I am I am using the simpledialog library (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/) and have included all the necessary JS and CSS files however I am unable to show the popup. What am I doing wrong? I don't see the popup.

```
$.ajax({

                        type: "post",
                        url: url,
                        data: $("#login").serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (msg) {

                        var message = msg.message;
                            if (message.type == "Success") {
                                window.location.replace("reminder_list.html");

                            } else if (message.type == "Error") {


        alert("login error"); //THIS SHOWS

 $(this).simpledialog({ //THIS DOES NOT SHOW
            'mode': 'bool',
            'prompt': 'Login Failed: ' + message.content,
            'buttons': {
                'OK': {
                    click: function () {
                        $('#dialogoutput').text('OK');
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: We need more detail, please post the html

Comment: What event and element is this code attached to?

Comment: I have updated my code to show that it gets called in the success handler of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was able to make it work by not using "this" keyword and replacing it with the actual page div. Somewhere somehow simpledialog was getting confused and/or this was not what it needed to be. Appreciate all those who looked into this.

Comment: Simpledialog has to attach to something in the DOM.  When attached to a click event, sometimes what is stored in the "this" keyword is indeed a DOM element.  In your example, it's probably the local scope of the Ajax function at that point - at any rate, providing an actual element would be the way to go.